# Cakephp: HasOne Relationship

Tags: cakephp, has-one

I'm trying to model the following:

A journey has an id, a fromCity and a toCity.

My DB looks like this:

Table journey:

```
id | fromCity | toCity
1    2           4
2    4           2
```

Table fromCity:

```
id  | name
2     paris
4     london
```

I have models defined for the city and for the journey.

In my model file for the journey I want to declare a $hasOne filed in order resolve the fromCity id to the city's name.

I tried to follow the CakePHP tutorial on hasOne (http://book.cakephp.org/view/80/hasOne) but I can't wrap my head around how to resolve two foreign keys.

Can someone please explain to me how a `var $hasone = ...` has to look for this case?

Edit: The models:

```
<?php class City extends AppModel { var $name='City';} ?> 

<?php class Journey extends AppModel { var $name='Journey'; /*var $hasOne=array(...)*/} ?>
```

**Edit 2:**

```
var $hasOne = array(
   'CityFrom' => array(
      'className'    => 'City',
      'conditions'   => 'Journey.fromAirport = CityFrom.id',
      'dependent'    => true,
      'foreignKey'  => 'id = Journey.fromCity'    ),
   'CityTo' => array (
      'className' => 'City',
      'conditions'   => 'Journey.toCity = CityTo.id',
      'dependent' => true,
      'foreignKey' => 'id = Journey.toCity'
   )
   );
```

Seems to work for the first entry of the journey table. All other's values are null. I think the problem occours from having two columns with the same name in this query.

Comment: care to share the model?

Comment: <?php class City extends AppModel { var $name='City';} ?> and <?php class Journey extends AppModel { var $name='Journey'; /*var $hasOne=array(...)*/} ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rin mentioned,you need to use `beLongsTo` instead of `hasOne`.Here's a example about [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) from Cookbook.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your link leads to `1.2` docs, you probably downloaded `1.3`.

In `1.3`, you should probably also use `belongsTo` on `FromCity` and `ToCity` Models (but I could be wrong, long time ago I used it :)